# object cannot be set - either read-only property or no setter found

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am having trouble over simply assigning a value to a UI Button:

```
//Assume rect is defined
rect = CGRectMake(13, 10, 48, 48);
profileButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
profileButton.buttonType = UIButtonTypeCustom;
```

I am getting "object cannot be set - either read-only property or setter found" when trying to assign the buttonType to UIButtonTypeCustom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `buttonType` is a read-only property. You can only create buttons of a specific type with `buttonWithType:`.

```
profileButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom] retain];
profileButton.frame = CGRectMake(13, 10, 48, 48);
```

(Not knowing what `profileButton` is, but assuming it is not a retaining property)

Comment: That did the trick. I will need to keep this in mind when initializing. Thanks!